# Is it possible to create a reaction to a certain number of lock button clicks using swift?

Tags: iphone, swift

Is it possible to enact a reaction to a certain number of lock button clicks in swift application?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean the lock screen of an iOS device. This is not possible. Apple does not provide a means of editing that. People can use jailbroken devices to accomplish something like this; however, that is not necessarily approved by Apple.